# How to get ObjectID and search for specific ObjectID in CoreData in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am currently working on a project with a **multi user system**. The user is able to create new profiles which are saved persistently using **CoreData**.

My problem is: Only one profile can be the **active one at a single time**, so I would like to get the **ObjectID** of the created profile and save it to **UserDefaults**.

Further I was thinking that as soon as I need the data of the active profile, I can simply get the ObjectID from UserDefaults and execute a **READ - Request** which only gives me back the **result** with that **specific ObjectID**.

***My code so far for SAVING THE DATA:***

```swift
// 1. Create new profile entry to the context.
let newProfile = Profiles(context: context)
newProfile.idProfileImage = idProfileImage
newProfile.timeCreated = Date()
newProfile.gender = gender
newProfile.name = name
newProfile.age = age
newProfile.weight = weight

// 2. Save the Object ID to User Defaults for "activeUser".
// ???????????????????
// ???????????????????

// 3. Try to save the new profile by saving the context to the persistent container.
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("Error saving context \(error)")
}
```

***My code so far for READING THE DATA***

```swift
// 1. Creates an request that is just pulling all the data.
let request: NSFetchRequest<Profiles> = Profiles.fetchRequest()

// 2. Try to fetch the request, can throw an error.
do {
    let result = try context.fetch(request)
} catch {
    print("Error reading data \(error)")
}
```

As you can see, I **haven't been able** to implement **Part 2 of the first code block**. The new profile gets saved but the ObjectID isn't saved to UserDefaults.

Also **Party 1 of the second code block** is not the final goal. The request just gives you back all the data of that entity, not only the one with the ObjectID I stored in User Defaults.

I hope you guys have an idea on how to solve this problem.
**Thanks for your help in advance guys!**

Comment: Why not just add an attribute, isCurrent, to your entity, rather than mixing up UserDefaults and CoreData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `NSManagedObjectID` does not conform to one of the types handled by `UserDefaults`, you'll have to use another way to represent the object id. Luckily, `NSManagedObjectID` has a `uriRepresentation()` that returns a URL, which can be stored in `UserDefaults`.

Assuming you are using a `NSPersistentContainer`, here's an extension that will handle the storage and retrieval of a active user `Profile`:

```swift
extension NSPersistentContainer {
    private var managedObjectIDKey: String {
        return "ActiveUserObjectID"
    }

    var activeUser: Profile? {
        get {
            guard let url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: managedObjectIDKey) else {
                return nil
            }

            guard let managedObjectID = persistentStoreCoordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: url) else {
                return nil
            }

            return viewContext.object(with: managedObjectID) as? Profile
        }
        set {
            guard let newValue = newValue else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: managedObjectIDKey)
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.objectID.uriRepresentation(), forKey: managedObjectIDKey)
        }
    }
}
```

This uses a method on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` to construct a `NSManagedObjectID` from a URI representation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It looks really good. I do fully understand the get part but can't figure out, why the set part needs this guard statement. Can you clarify this for me pls.

Comment: `activeProfile` here is defined as optional with the **?**. So if you set `activeUser = nil`, then the value will be removed from the UserDefaults. Hence the guard in the set... If no value (nil), then removed, if there is a value than update/set.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks you. That makes sense!

Comment: I have encountered another problem. When I do delete an inactive profile, which Object ID is not saved to the UserDefaults, the app is not able to retrieve the current active user after the deletion. Is there any chance that object IDs change after deleting another object?